# Determining which words were matched in a fuzzy search

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm running a fuzzy search, and need to see which words were matched. For example, if I am searching for the query `testing`, and it matches a field with the sentence `The boy was resting`, I need to be able to know that the match was due to the word `resting`.

I tried setting the parameter `explain = true`, but it doesn't seem to contain the information I need. Any thoughts?

Comment: Sadly, I don't see anything in the Fuzzy documentation..I would guess that Explain is your best bet, but it sounds like it doesn't haven it.  I'm interested as well.

Comment: @SamSullivan After a bit more research, I found the answer. It's a feature called highlighting, which I've posted in an answer below.

Comment: Ah, you actually wanted it for highlighting? XY-problem. :) Letting my answer be there for posterity.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Alright, this is what I was looking for:

After a bit of research, I found the [Highlighting feature](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-body.html#request-body-search-highlighting) of elasticsearch.

By default it returns a snippet of context surrounding the match, but you can set the fragment size to the query length to return only the exact match. For example:

```
{
    query : query,
    highlight : {
        "fields" : {
            'text' : {
                "fragment_size" : query.length
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `explain` should give you some clues, although not very easily available.

If you run the following, also available at https://www.found.no/play/gist/daa46f0e14273198691a , you should see e.g. `description: "weight(text:nesting^0.85714287 in 1) […]`, `description: "weight(text:testing in 1) [PerFieldSimilarity] […]` and so on in the hit's `_explanation`.

```
#!/bin/bash

export ELASTICSEARCH_ENDPOINT="http://localhost:9200"

# Create indexes

curl -XPUT "$ELASTICSEARCH_ENDPOINT/play" -d '{}'

# Index documents
curl -XPOST "$ELASTICSEARCH_ENDPOINT/_bulk?refresh=true" -d '
{"index":{"_index":"play","_type":"type"}}
{"text":"The boy was resting"}
{"index":{"_index":"play","_type":"type"}}
{"text":"The bird was testing while nesting"}
'

# Do searches

curl -XPOST "$ELASTICSEARCH_ENDPOINT/_search?pretty" -d '
{
    "query": {
        "match": {
            "text": {
                "query": "testing",
                "fuzziness": 1
            }
        }
    },
    "explain": true
}
'
```