# Elasticsearch exact highlighting

Tags: elasticsearch

I want to recieve highlighted text as list of highlighted words, not whole text or fragments.

My query is percolator query:

```
{'doc': {'field_name': text}, "highlight": {
        "fields": {
            "field_name": {}
        }
    }, 'size': 100}
```

For example, by the default i receive

```
field_name: ['some text ...<em>word1</em> ... some text ...<em>word2</em> some text...']
```

I want to receive:

```
field_name: ['word1', 'word2']
```

How can I do it?

Answer (score 1):

```
  "highlight": {
    "fields": {
      "field_name": {
        "fragment_size": q,
        "number_of_fragments": 100
      }
    }
  }
```

will do the trick

Answer (score -1):

I was also wandering how to do this and I haven't implemented it yet but I found another [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26945217/find-actual-matching-word-when-using-fuzzy-query-in-elastic-search) on stackoverflow that I think it will help.

You should be able to find the match on the `"highlight"` key of the elasticsearch response