# Get terms matching prefix query in ElasticSearch

Tags: elasticsearch

The result of ElasticSearch prefix query returns only the documents matching the query. Is there a way I can configure the query to also return the "**exact term(s)**" for each document that resulted in a match?

Answer (score 2):

Well, using [Highlighting](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-highlighting.html) you get the text with the matched words highlighted. Ie:

```
GET /_search
{
  "query": {
    "prefix": { "DESCRIPTION": "arthu"}
  },
    "highlight": {
        "fields" : {
            "DESCRIPTION" : {}
        }
    }
}
```

Retrieves something like:

```
{
        "_index": "abc",
        "_type": "xyz",
        "_id": "107507",
        "_score": 1,
        "_source": {
          "DESCRIPTION": "Arthur: Attack of the Turbo Tibbles/D.W. Tricks the Tooth Fairy"
        },
        "highlight": {
          "DESCRIPTION": [
            "<em>Arthur</em>: Attack of the Turbo Tibbles/D.W. Tricks the Tooth Fairy"
          ]
        }
      }
```

You can also customize the wrapping tag (em). But I'm not sure how to extract only the matched words from there.

Take a look at this thread anyway. I don't understand the implementation but it may help: [Determining which words were matched in a fuzzy search](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21764766/determining-which-words-were-matched-in-a-fuzzy-search)

Basically he proposed to do this:

```
GET /common_clarovideo/grupo/_search
{
  "_source": [
    "NOMBRE_INTERNO"
  ],
  "query": {
    "prefix": { "NOMBRE_INTERNO": "arthu"}
  },
    "highlight": {
        "fields" : {
            "NOMBRE_INTERNO" : {"fragment_size" : 5}
        }
    }
}
```

Meaning "fragment_size" must match the length of your term. Hope this helps.

Comment: I thought about using highlighting but that requires the source to be stored. In my case, I am not storing source due to sensitive data.

Comment: I think I should be more specific with my problem. Given a prefix query, I need to find all the terms matching the prefix and the count of documents matching each term.

So, another issue with highlighting approach is that I will have to paginate through all pages to get the count which could cause problem with large number of documents.

Answer (score 1):

Yes.you need to use term instead match and you will get the exact term.
See [documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-terms-query.html)

Comment: I can't use term because all the fields are analyzed. Also, _source is not enabled for me.