# Using SearchKick to display spelling correction

Tags: searchkick

Does anyone know if its possible to get the searchkick gem to explain itself when it uses misspellings?

Ie on a search for "Penut", I should be able to know that the results returned are actually really for "Peanut". Pretty much in the same way that google works, it has the "Showing search results for Peanut" when searching for "Penut".

Answer (score 0):

You can get suggestions for the search query (not the results) by using Searchkick's [suggestion feature](https://github.com/ankane/searchkick#suggestions).

You can try to use highlighting to get them from the results.

```
class Product < ApplicationRecord
  searchkick highlight: [:name]
end

def parse_highlights(name)
  Nokogiri::HTML(name).css("em").map { |v| v.text }
end

products = Product.search("penut", highlight: true)
products.with_highlights.each do |product, highlights|
  parse_highlights(highlights[:name])
end
```

[Similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21764766/determining-which-words-were-matched-in-a-fuzzy-search) about Elasticsearch.